# STL--MAP--Adding string as key and class object as value

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, stl

The code explains insertion of pair to map wherein the key type is string and the value is the reference to a class object. However, there are 3overloading functions such as overloading= operator, overloading< operator and overloading == operator.. Can anyone pls explain me why the overloading of here??

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <map>
    using namespace std;

    class AAA
    {
       friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &, const AAA &);

       public:
          int x;
          int y;
          float z;

          AAA();
          AAA(const AAA &);
          ~AAA(){};
          AAA &operator=(const AAA &rhs);
          int operator==(const AAA &rhs) const;
          int operator<(const AAA &rhs) const;
    };

    AAA::AAA()   // Constructor
    {
       x = 0;
       y = 0;
       z = 0;
    }

    AAA::AAA(const AAA &copyin)   // Copy constructor to handle pass by value.
    {                             
       x = copyin.x;
       y = copyin.y;
       z = copyin.z;
    }

    ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, const AAA &aaa)
    {
       output << aaa.x << ' ' << aaa.y << ' ' << aaa.z << endl;
       return output;
    }

    AAA& AAA::operator=(const AAA &rhs)
    {
       this->x = rhs.x;
       this->y = rhs.y;
       this->z = rhs.z;
       return *this;
    }

    int AAA::operator==(const AAA &rhs) const
    {
       if( this->x != rhs.x) return 0;
       if( this->y != rhs.y) return 0;
       if( this->z != rhs.z) return 0;
       return 1;
    }

    int AAA::operator<(const AAA &rhs) const
    {
       if( this->x == rhs.x && this->y == rhs.y && this->z < rhs.z) return 1;
       if( this->x == rhs.x && this->y < rhs.y) return 1;
       if( this->x < rhs.x ) return 1;
       return 0;
    }

    main()
    {
       map<string, AAA> M;
       AAA Ablob ;

       Ablob.x=7;
       Ablob.y=2;
       Ablob.z=4.2355;
       M["A"] = Ablob;

       Ablob.x=5;
       M["B"] = Ablob;

       Ablob.z=3.2355;
       M["C"] = Ablob;

       Ablob.x=3;
       Ablob.y=7;
       Ablob.z=7.2355;
       M["D"] = Ablob;

       for( map<string, AAA>::iterator ii=M.begin(); ii!=M.end(); ++ii)
       {
           cout << (*ii).first << ": " << (*ii).second << endl;
       }

       return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

They're not overloads, they're definitions of the operators.  In this particular case, the copy constructor and assignment operator do what the defaults would do, so they should be omitted.  The comparison operators should return a `bool` instead of an `int`, and the `<` comparison could be written more efficiently.  Neither comparison is used in the code given so they are also superfluous.  If `AAA` was the key in the map then they'd be necessary, but since it is the value they aren't needed there.

Incidentally, you can define your for loop as

```
for (auto ii = M.begin(); ii != M.end(); ++i)
```

unless your compiler is old enough that it does not support this use of `auto`.

Comment: follow @1201ProgramAlarm if AAA would be the key then how does < comparison operator will work? can u pls elaborate its working?